# Why Does SQL Error When I Forget the @ on Variable Passed a Procedure Parameter?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I had a typo of missing an @ from a use of a variable. Normally SQL will compain about an undeclared variable. However in the case where it is used a sproc parameter sql server doesn't complain. It simply infers some singe quotes and moves on.

Can anyone explain why example C does not error?

```
--Ex A. Error
SELECT id

--Ex B. Error
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnTest (
  @id NVARCHAR(4)
) RETURNS NVARCHAR(4) AS BEGIN 
  RETURN @id 
END
GO
DECLARE @id NVARCHAR(4) 
SET @id= 'bob'
SELECT dbo.fnTest(@id) --missing my @, this should be @id
--SELECT dbo.fnTest(id) --missing my @, this should be @id
GO
DROP FUNCTION fnTest

--Ex C. No Error
CREATE PROC spTest (
  @id NVARCHAR(4)
) AS 
  SELECT @id
GO
DECLARE @id NVARCHAR(4) 
SET @id= 'bob'
EXEC spTest id --missing my @, this should be @id
GO
DROP PROC spTest
```

Comment: Thanks, your question definitely gave me some insight upon declaring variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same reason this has always worked:

```
EXEC sp_who2 active;
```

Versus the expected:

```
EXEC sp_who2 N'active';
```

Stored procedures are able to accept an input string without single quotes and still treat it as a string, as long as it doesn't have any special characters like spaces or dashes.

**Why does it work for procedures and not for functions?**

Doubt you'll get a satisfactory answer to that question, unless you can find the developers who worked on very early versions of SQL Server (well, probably Sybase) and buy them a beer and coax it out of them. Just one of those little implementation details that is "that's the way it works; there is no *why*." Most likely the two code paths were written by different developers, in a time where ship dates were prioritized over consistency. (Oh, wait a minute.)

---

PS you should always name your parameters, and [you should always use the schema prefix when creating or referencing objects](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix), e.g.

```
EXEC dbo.spTest @id = @id;
```

This prevents you from the typo you came across and also protects you from underlying changes to the stored procedure (e.g. someone sticks a new, optional parameter at the beginning of the parameter list).

Comment: Although I don't know the answer to the question "why omitting single quotes doesn't work for functions?", I think it's just as well that it doesn't. Otherwise how would the parser be able to tell a quote-less string from e.g. a column reference? With SPs it's never an issue because a stored procedure is never executed in a context where referencing a column name would be valid.

Comment: By the way, this phenomenon may be connected with the fact that you cannot use the result of a function as an argument directly. Apparently, if an argument starts with a `@`, it's interpreted as a variable, otherwise it's a value of some kind of a generic type (if it doesn't convert to a number, it's a string, but only as long as it qualifies as a valid non-delimited identifier, I guess).

Comment: That a good answer. And I agree that explicit naming of the param is a valuable defensive coding practice. However, in this case that particular point is skew. I get the same behavior with the same typo EXEC spTest @id=id.

Comment: @Karl right, I didn't intend to suggest that better coding style would eliminate errors entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Like any interpreter, TSQL sometimes makes assumptions instead of generating an error.

Lets take a look at what is going in the SQL Engine by doing a trace.

[image]

The two characters **id** are passed to the stored procedure as a parameter.  It is type casted to a string and returned as the result.  This is because EXEC call is just looking for strings to interpret into code, it does not generate an error.

```
Basically late binding.
```

Now, lets do a trace on the SELECT call to a function.  The engine knows that it is a SELECT statement.  Because you can only pass variables or columns to a function, it notices that there is no @, so it is not a variable.  Thus, it must be a column.  But since there is no from clause, it raises an error.

```
Basically early binding.
```

[image]